# Minifying JS & CSS in Stencil Utils - BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, css, seo, minify, bigcommerce

I'm looking for a way to compress the JavaScript and CSS files on a BigCommerce site that is using a Stencil-Utils theme. Other CMS I've used have tools built-in but this one seems to be a bit more hands-on any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Stencil, bundles all the JavaScript modules into a single file & will automatically minify your modules. In addition with Stencil’s use of pre-built package managers for distributing JavaScript’s components in the correct directories, Stencil themes include an API for running JavaScript on a per-page basis to help run any custom logic your theme may have. [Here is some documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjEyNDYyOTg-adding-javascript#development-options) on development options of implementing custom JS modules in your Stencil theme to be automatically bundled and minified.

In addition to Stencils bundling and minification of JavaScript modules, Stencil themes support both Sass and SCSS. Along with the JavaScript modules, the nested CSS properties are all stored in the Stencil’s [theme assets directory](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDcyNA-theme-assets) i.e. ‘assets/js/’ & ‘assets/scss/’. If you are looking to add your own custom Sass files to your Stencil theme and initiate auto-compilation of those files. Include the associated tag in your HTML markup to isolate your custom styles, then place it at this paths location ‘/assets/scss/customname.scss’ using a filename prefix of your choosing and import the custom file into theme.scss via ‘@import “customname”;’. Once you make sure that the theme.scss is located in templates/layout/base.html/ via ‘{{stylesheet '/assets/css/theme.scss'}} ‘. You can then use the Stencil CLI to recompile your custom Sass files to the specified {theme-name}/assets/css/theme.scss file with the ‘stencil start’  command.
Here is some great documentation on utilizing [Custom Sass Functions](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDcyMQ-custom-sass-functions) and [Compiling custom Sass files](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDcyMQ-custom-sass-functions#compiling-custom-sass-files) with Stencil, as well as [Bundling and Pushing a Theme](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDY4Mg-bundling-and-pushing-a-theme).

Hope this Helps.